# Optimizing for loop for speed

Tags: r

The below code loops through roughly 120 variables in `vars`.  Presently the file takes about 80 seconds to complete, which is quite long.  I was curious if anyone saw any low hanging fruit in terms of speeding up my code.  I have 32 cores, but changing cores = 32 for DoParallel didn't gain me much.  Perhaps rewriting the for loop to an apply?

```
# rm(list = ls()) #clears the workspace


library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(foreach) 
library(doParallel)
library(forecast)

# set up
options(scipen = 999)  #removes scientific notation
registerDoParallel(cores = 32) 

# read data
proj_path = "P:/R"
Macro <- read.csv("P:/Earnest/Old/R/Input.csv")

# prep data
source("P:/Earnest/Old/R/VarTS.R")  #Calls variables

cbind.fill <- function(...){
  nm <- list(...) 
  nm <- lapply(nm, as.matrix)
  n <- max(sapply(nm, nrow)) 
  do.call(cbind, lapply(nm, function (x) 
    rbind(x, matrix(, n-nrow(x), ncol(x))))) 
}

len <- nrow(Macro)

# Loads all variable names from Macro and Macro2
vars_macro = names(Macro)[!names(Macro) %in% c("qtrs", "y", "s1", "s2", "s3", "date")]  #Returns names in Macro not in "qtrs", "y", "s1", "s2", "s3"
vars_macro2 = names(Macro2)[!names(Macro2) %in% c("y", "s1", "s2", "s3")]
vars_macro3 = names(Macro3)[!names(Macro3) %in% c("y", "s1", "s2", "s3")]
vars_macroall = names(Macroall)[!names(Macroall) %in% c("y", "s1", "s2", "s3")]
vars = c(vars_macro, vars_macro2, vars_macro3)
consensus = Macro[[2]][len]

fit    <- list()
output <- list()
forecast <- list()


for(m in vars){
  thedata <- get(m)
  output[[m]] <- list() # treat output as a list-of-lists 
  fit[[m]] <- list() # treat fit as a list-of-lists

  for(z in rev(1:6)) {
    tryCatch(  #added tryCatch because for loop was breaking on error around number of dimensions
      expr = {
        x <- thedata[1:(len-z),1:1]
        x <- ts((x), start = c(2016, 3), frequency = 4)
        y <- Macro[1:(len-z),2:2]
        y <- ts((y), start = c(2016, 3), frequency = 4)
        t <- thedata[(len+1-z):(len+1-z),1:1]
        t <- ts((t), start = c(2018, 4), frequency = 4) 

        #fit model
        fit[[m]][[z]] <-auto.arima(y,xreg=x,seasonal=TRUE,parallel = TRUE,num.cores = NULL) #D=1 enforces seasonality
        output[[m]][[z]] <- forecast(fit[[m]][[z]],xreg=t)$mean
      },
      error = function(e){
        message("* Caught an error on itertion", m)
        print(e)
      }
    )}}

output
output2 <- matrix(unlist(output), ncol = length(vars))
output2 <- output2[nrow(output2):1,]


matrixoutput <- output2[1:5,1:length(vars)]
matrixactual <- matrix(Macro[(len-5):(len-1),2:2])
matrixactual <- c(matrixactual)


MAPE <- colMeans(abs((matrixactual - matrixoutput) / matrixactual))
Forecast <- output2[6:6,1:length(vars)]
Delta <- ((Forecast - consensus) / consensus)
LastMAPE <- abs(((matrixoutput[5:5,] - matrixactual[5:5])/matrixactual[5:5]))

df <- data.frame(vars,Forecast, MAPE, Delta)
dflast <- data.frame(vars,Forecast, MAPE, LastMAPE, Delta )

df_macro1 = df[df$vars %in% vars_macro,]
df_macro1[17:17,] <- NA 
df <- df[with(df, order(MAPE)), ] #sorts after original variables
df_macro2 = df[df$vars %in% vars_macro2,]
df_macro2$blankVar = NA
df_macro3 = df[df$vars %in% vars_macro3,]
df_macro3$blankVar = NA
df_macroall = df[df$vars %in% vars_macroall,]
df_macroall$blankVar = NA
df_macro4 = df[df$vars %in% names(Macro4),]
df_macro4$blankVar = NA

df_macro5 = dflast[dflast$vars %in% vars_macroall,]
df_macro5 <- df_macro5[with(df_macro5, order(LastMAPE)), ] 
df_macro5$blankVar = NA

df_macro1 <- rbind.fill(df_macro1, df_macro5)

a = cbind.fill(df_macro1, df_macro2, df_macro3, df_macroall, df_macro4, df, consensus)

print(df, row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(a, "P:/Earnest/Old/R/OutputTSList.csv", row.names = F, na="")
```

Not sure if it helps, put providing dput(Macro)

```
dput(Macro)
structure(list(qtrs = structure(1:14, .Label = c("15_Q3", "15_Q4", 
"16_Q1", "16_Q2", "16_Q3", "16_Q4", "17_Q1", "17_Q2", "17_Q3", 
"17_Q4", "18_Q1", "18_Q2", "18_Q3", "QQ_New"), class = "factor"), 
    y = c(121.3, 131.1, 142.5, 156.4, 168.7, 176.2, 177, 186.6, 
    199.6, 208.4, 214, 226.2, 232.5, 233.3), c1372 = c(0.51798059487155, 
    0.605074600778554, 0.70840580233259, 0.796638389230915, 0.800936365512504, 
    0.862507422705653, 0.906587776772603, 0.965869599669482, 
    1.02057681299029, 1.0173665712577, 1.00815541019123, 1.11026857023261, 
    1.12549360199319, 1.17070543044674), c5244 = c(0.0158288398871533, 
    0.0186529717846534, 0.0335038479568057, 0.0322124481706554, 
    0.0473432307176583, 0.0372644166954006, 0.055124227441671, 
    0.0462947124597511, 0.0595395997947759, 0.079813226336006, 
    0.0632338684298483, 0.0359582444979424, 0.0399978873936274, 
    0.0363530147033467), c5640 = c(0.0695411232121069, 0.0711030107194139, 
    0.0768960904393596, 0.0937721113616879, 0.0912072768529112, 
    0.0948627915873504, 0.0898598251896699, 0.102519015439631, 
    0.117307571608132, 0.116512410019832, 0.112621649435311, 
    0.113373707050245, 0.11920732067264, 0.11385677519257), c6164 = c(0.165253620685311, 
    0.180939722142955, 0.204839371353829, 0.230388360169478, 
    0.245455819824873, 0.250222069413121, 0.267517323013963, 
    0.301455130772129, 0.312527568603722, 0.318684362849784, 
    0.336297671149745, 0.385321973576628, 0.393392171202544, 
    0.414026295628249), b1372 = c(0.220276379575007, 0.232259423605283, 
    0.239015099925248, 0.29722406784095, 0.305759227349267, 0.314812674203001, 
    0.373507924872403, 0.376216626537958, 0.450679682818151, 
    0.422160030256414, 0.398670890305128, 0.380896038096525, 
    0.339513818723946, 0.365265284571949), b5244 = c(0.0256963971001724, 
    0.0308736893223339, 0.0314727889765328, 0.0342560993718647, 
    0.0329261690808683, 0.0341169107838618, 0.0500316002161605, 
    0.057066652393088, 0.0637597978553195, 0.102100656473269, 
    0.109515398926193, 0.0509080775409312, 0.034576665601428, 
    0.037353167421955), b5640 = c(0.0610914743954476, 0.0681070468175109, 
    0.0680584203087885, 0.0737178858316377, 0.0657525044040775, 
    0.0634389081514569, 0.0655890933419926, 0.0689747904574716, 
    0.0653176858840394, 0.0683221933318993, 0.0692822163266979, 
    0.0648739229545749, 0.0613089747918081, 0.0681802570906864
    ), b6164 = c(0.106769764392002, 0.117293493937739, 0.128632140410947, 
    0.146139699267301, 0.15999997720466, 0.170137316488036, 0.188733545209946, 
    0.192072924866328, 0.200314760101575, 0.206572493122192, 
    0.21531555211795, 0.187877279779437, 0.161952291803993, 0.160944253061549
    ), v1372 = c(0.00268999015293817, 0.00312395322452212, 0.00339511453015627, 
    0.00345686458302532, 0.00342490795325169, 0.0036875222492476, 
    0.00361618758896395, 0.00355297766248592, 0.00386182842589497, 
    0.00356454140879668, 0.00347191673410727, 0.00363595803623375, 
    0.00374222181870868, 0.00371078757415556), v5244 = c(0.000480051602474059, 
    0.00042588395300854, 0.0005605459198973, 0.000529571165782351, 
    0.00057240403833901, 0.000468179333138233, 0.000653241119295764, 
    0.000455570432040571, 0.000535395675184177, 0.00138501873189088, 
    0.00114060122318986, 0.000320532455933637, 0.000333175133801828, 
    0.000314970929257286), v5640 = c(0.000839152227642805, 0.000878653169087127, 
    0.00086250329626335, 0.000928749230480325, 0.000952705037621405, 
    0.0009145284719627, 0.000862662166602764, 0.000861675351344781, 
    0.000900555099811469, 0.000846321708899047, 0.000869990227889332, 
    0.000889602926022706, 0.000847332392691765, 0.000745645512078392
    ), v6164 = c(0.00174116886286925, 0.00190736857470478, 0.00204206516831707, 
    0.00208434471661794, 0.0022434016778137, 0.00215767033473045, 
    0.00216675412062837, 0.00211218329813293, 0.00222445645154173, 
    0.00210022505915819, 0.00196775099859493, 0.00205851514065652, 
    0.00187858647947073, 0.00198038712502613), bv1372 = c(0.00142360941776777, 
    0.00151188642851632, 0.00157840305106086, 0.00168297006976765, 
    0.00157809381382463, 0.00180299614944991, 0.00285754565464732, 
    0.0026777621396315, 0.00314015380649578, 0.00293231409618566, 
    0.00290686161843522, 0.00248890293023165, 0.00168251123284542, 
    0.00179265933772828), bv5244 = c(0.000582722401914161, 0.000711777965499918, 
    0.000761910243648493, 0.000805854835145839, 0.000736857013245957, 
    0.000833892120648163, 0.0013602408759186, 0.0015050207801102, 
    0.0016936381650882, 0.00295309680744017, 0.0031773319850428, 
    0.00106962198904438, 0.000593441969063344, 0.000574791244792
    ), bv5640 = c(0.00115351432401665, 0.00132428243672085, 0.00136224787475921, 
    0.00141606633583978, 0.00116049625522213, 0.000858609082150378, 
    0.000908098663997447, 0.000935982449156028, 0.000899912473850066, 
    0.000835053614508394, 0.000872837946479594, 0.000833516238462063, 
    0.000726891442062557, 0.000774037355521608), bv6164 = c(0.000926271545004555, 
    0.00105864530300842, 0.00109611375444535, 0.00117219207771791, 
    0.00122508269987305, 0.00135585463133827, 0.00195926581029822, 
    0.00187620455518874, 0.00206572868014085, 0.00213169451258196, 
    0.00205259028597028, 0.00136013066654879, 0.000919533667669498, 
    0.0010609844820593), s1 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), s2 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), s3 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "2018-09-30", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Finally, here are how all variables are defined, i.e., the below is what is contained in VarTS.R (source("P:/Earnest/Old/R/VarTS.R")  #Calls variables

```
#Let's define some variables

c1372 <- Macro["c1372"]
c5244 <- Macro["c5244"]
c5640 <- Macro["c5640"]
c6164 <- Macro["c6164"]
b1372 <- Macro["b1372"]
b5244 <- Macro["b5244"]
b5640 <- Macro["b5640"]
b6164 <- Macro["b6164"]
v1372 <- Macro["v1372"]
v5244 <- Macro["v5244"]
v5640 <- Macro["v5640"]
v6164 <- Macro["v6164"]
bv1372 <- Macro["bv1372"]
bv5244 <- Macro["bv5244"]
bv5640 <- Macro["bv5640"]
bv6164 <- Macro["bv6164"]


X1372C5244C <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c1372", "c5244")])
X1372C5640C <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c1372", "c5640")])
X1372C6164C <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c1372", "c6164")])
X1372C1372B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c1372", "b1372")])
X1372C5244B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c1372", "b5244")])
X1372C5640B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c1372", "b5640")])
X1372C6164B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c1372", "b6164")])

X5244C5640C <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c5244", "c5640")])
X5244C6164C <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c5244", "c6164")])
X5244C1372B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c5244", "b1372")])
X5244C5244B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c5244", "b5244")])
X5244C5640B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c5244", "b5640")])
X5244C6164B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c5244", "b6164")])

X5640C6164C <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c5640", "c6164")])
X5640C1372B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c5640", "b1372")])
X5640C5244B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c5640", "b5244")])
X5640C5640B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c5640", "b5640")])
X5640C6164B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c5640", "b6164")])

X6164C1372B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c6164", "b1372")])
X6164C5244B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c6164", "b5244")])
X6164C5640B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c6164", "b5640")])
X6164C6164B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c6164", "b6164")])

X1372B5244B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("b1372", "b5244")])
X1372B5640B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("b1372", "b5640")])
X1372B6164B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("b1372", "b6164")])

X5244B5640B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("b5244", "b5640")])
X5244B6164B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("b5244", "b6164")])

X5640B6164B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("b5640", "b6164")])

X1372C5640C1372B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c1372", "c5640", "b1372" )])
X1372C5640C5640B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c1372", "c5640", "b5640" )])
X1372C5640C6164B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c1372", "c5640", "b6164" )])

X1372C6164C1372B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c1372", "c6164", "b1372" )])
X1372C6164C5640B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c1372", "c6164", "b5640" )])
X1372C6164C6164B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c1372", "c6164", "b6164" )])

X6164C5640C1372B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c6164", "c5640", "b1372" )])
X6164C5640C5640B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c6164", "c5640", "b5640" )])
X6164C5640C6164B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c6164", "c5640", "b6164" )])

XAll3Card <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c1372","c5640","c6164")])
XAll3Card1372B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c1372","c5640","c6164","b1372")])
XAll3Card5640B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c1372","c5640","c6164","b5640")])
XAll3Card6164B <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c1372","c5640","c6164","b6164")])

XAll3Bank <- rowMeans(Macro[c("b1372","b5640","b6164")])
XAll3Bank1372C <- rowMeans(Macro[c("b1372","b5640","b6164","c1372")])
XAll3Bank5640C <- rowMeans(Macro[c("b1372","b5640","b6164","c5640")])
XAll3Bank6164C <- rowMeans(Macro[c("b1372","b5640","b6164","c6164")])

XAll13725640 <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c1372", "b1372", "c5640", "b5640")])
XAll13726164 <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c1372", "b1372", "c6164", "b6164")])
XAll56406164 <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c5640", "b5640", "c6164", "b6164")])

XAll4Card <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c1372", "c5244", "c5640", "c6164")])
XAll4Bank <- rowMeans(Macro[c("b1372", "b5244", "b5640", "b6164")])
XAll6 <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c1372","c5640","c6164","b1372","b5640","b6164")])
XAll8 <- rowMeans(Macro[c("c1372", "c5244", "c5640", "c6164","b1372", "b5244", "b5640", "b6164")])





X1372V5244V <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v1372", "v5244")])
X1372V5640V <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v1372", "v5640")])
X1372V6164V <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v1372", "v6164")])
X1372V1372BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v1372", "bv1372")])
X1372V5244BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v1372", "bv5244")])
X1372V5640BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v1372", "bv5640")])
X1372V6164BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v1372", "bv6164")])

X5244V5640V <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v5244", "v5640")])
X5244V6164V <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v5244", "v6164")])
X5244V1372BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v5244", "bv1372")])
X5244V5244BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v5244", "bv5244")])
X5244V5640BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v5244", "bv5640")])
X5244V6164BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v5244", "bv6164")])

X5640V6164V <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v5640", "v6164")])
X5640V1372BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v5640", "bv1372")])
X5640V5244BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v5640", "bv5244")])
X5640V5640BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v5640", "bv5640")])
X5640V6164BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v5640", "bv6164")])

X6164V1372BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v6164", "bv1372")])
X6164V5244BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v6164", "bv5244")])
X6164V5640BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v6164", "bv5640")])
X6164V6164BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v6164", "bv6164")])

X1372BV5244BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("bv1372", "bv5244")])
X1372BV5640BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("bv1372", "bv5640")])
X1372BV6164BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("bv1372", "bv6164")])

X5244BV5640BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("bv5244", "bv5640")])
X5244BV6164BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("bv5244", "bv6164")])

X5640BV6164BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("bv5640", "bv6164")])

X1372V5640V1372BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v1372", "v5640", "bv1372" )])
X1372V5640V5640BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v1372", "v5640", "bv5640" )])
X1372V5640V6164BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v1372", "v5640", "bv6164" )])

X1372V6164V1372BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v1372", "v6164", "bv1372" )])
X1372V6164V5640BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v1372", "v6164", "bv5640" )])
X1372V6164V6164BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v1372", "v6164", "bv6164" )])

X6164V5640V1372BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v6164", "v5640", "bv1372" )])
X6164V5640V5640BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v6164", "v5640", "bv5640" )])
X6164V5640V6164BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v6164", "v5640", "bv6164" )])

XAll3CardV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v1372","v5640","v6164")])
XAll3Card1372BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v1372","v5640","v6164","bv1372")])
XAll3Card5640BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v1372","v5640","v6164","bv5640")])
XAll3Card6164BV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v1372","v5640","v6164","bv6164")])

XAll3BankV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("bv1372","bv5640","bv6164")])
XAll3Bank1372V <- rowMeans(Macro[c("bv1372","bv5640","bv6164","v1372")])
XAll3Bank5640V <- rowMeans(Macro[c("bv1372","bv5640","bv6164","v5640")])
XAll3Bank6164V <- rowMeans(Macro[c("bv1372","bv5640","bv6164","v6164")])


XAll13725640V <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v1372", "bv1372", "v5640", "bv5640")])
XAll13726164V <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v1372", "bv1372", "v6164", "bv6164")])
XAll56406164V <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v5640", "bv5640", "v6164", "bv6164")])

XAll4CardV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v1372", "v5244", "v5640", "v6164")])
XAll4BankV <- rowMeans(Macro[c("bv1372", "bv5244", "bv5640", "bv6164")])
XAll6V <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v1372","v5640","v6164","bv1372","bv5640","bv6164")])
XAll8V <- rowMeans(Macro[c("v1372", "v5244", "v5640", "v6164","bv1372", "bv5244", "bv5640", "bv6164")])




X1372C5244C <- data.frame(X1372C5244C)
X1372C5640C <- data.frame(X1372C5640C)
X1372C6164C <- data.frame(X1372C6164C)
X1372C1372B <- data.frame(X1372C1372B)
X1372C5244B <- data.frame(X1372C5244B)
X1372C5640B <- data.frame(X1372C5640B)
X1372C6164B <- data.frame(X1372C6164B)

X5244C5640C <- data.frame(X5244C5640C)
X5244C6164C <- data.frame(X5244C6164C)
X5244C1372B <- data.frame(X5244C1372B)
X5244C5244B <- data.frame(X5244C5244B)
X5244C5640B <- data.frame(X5244C5640B)
X5244C6164B <- data.frame(X5244C6164B)

X5640C6164C <- data.frame(X5640C6164C)
X5640C1372B <- data.frame(X5640C1372B)
X5640C5244B <- data.frame(X5640C5244B)
X5640C5640B <- data.frame(X5640C5640B)
X5640C6164B <- data.frame(X5640C6164B)

X6164C1372B <- data.frame(X6164C1372B)
X6164C5244B <- data.frame(X6164C5244B)
X6164C5640B <- data.frame(X6164C5640B)
X6164C6164B <- data.frame(X6164C6164B)

X1372B5244B <- data.frame(X1372B5244B)
X1372B5640B <- data.frame(X1372B5640B)
X1372B6164B <- data.frame(X1372B6164B)

X5244B5640B <- data.frame(X5244B5640B)
X5244B6164B <- data.frame(X5244B6164B)

X5640B6164B <- data.frame(X5640B6164B)

X1372C5640C1372B <- data.frame(X1372C5640C1372B)
X1372C5640C5640B <- data.frame(X1372C5640C5640B)
X1372C5640C6164B <- data.frame(X1372C5640C6164B)

X1372C6164C1372B <- data.frame(X1372C6164C1372B)
X1372C6164C5640B <- data.frame(X1372C6164C5640B)
X1372C6164C6164B <- data.frame(X1372C6164C6164B)

X6164C5640C1372B <- data.frame(X6164C5640C1372B)
X6164C5640C5640B <- data.frame(X6164C5640C5640B)
X6164C5640C6164B <- data.frame(X6164C5640C6164B)

XAll3Card <- data.frame(XAll3Card)
XAll3Card1372B <- data.frame(XAll3Card1372B)
XAll3Card5640B <- data.frame(XAll3Card5640B)
XAll3Card6164B <- data.frame(XAll3Card6164B)

XAll3Bank <- data.frame(XAll3Bank)
XAll3Bank1372C <- data.frame(XAll3Bank1372C)
XAll3Bank5640C <- data.frame(XAll3Bank5640C)
XAll3Bank6164C <- data.frame(XAll3Bank6164C)

XAll13725640 <- data.frame(XAll13725640)
XAll13726164 <- data.frame(XAll13726164)
XAll56406164 <- data.frame(XAll56406164)

XAll4Card <- data.frame(XAll4Card)
XAll4Bank <- data.frame(XAll4Bank)
XAll6 <- data.frame(XAll6)
XAll8 <- data.frame(XAll8)




X1372V5244V <- data.frame(X1372V5244V)
X1372V5640V <- data.frame(X1372V5640V)
X1372V6164V <- data.frame(X1372V6164V)
X1372V1372BV <- data.frame(X1372V1372BV)
X1372V5244BV <- data.frame(X1372V5244BV)
X1372V5640BV <- data.frame(X1372V5640BV)
X1372V6164BV <- data.frame(X1372V6164BV)

X5244V5640V <- data.frame(X5244V5640V)
X5244V6164V <- data.frame(X5244V6164V)
X5244V1372BV <- data.frame(X5244V1372BV)
X5244V5244BV <- data.frame(X5244V5244BV)
X5244V5640BV <- data.frame(X5244V5640BV)
X5244V6164BV <- data.frame(X5244V6164BV)

X5640V6164V <- data.frame(X5640V6164V)
X5640V1372BV <- data.frame(X5640V1372BV)
X5640V5244BV <- data.frame(X5640V5244BV)
X5640V5640BV <- data.frame(X5640V5640BV)
X5640V6164BV <- data.frame(X5640V6164BV)

X6164V1372BV <- data.frame(X6164V1372BV)
X6164V5244BV <- data.frame(X6164V5244BV)
X6164V5640BV <- data.frame(X6164V5640BV)
X6164V6164BV <- data.frame(X6164V6164BV)

X1372BV5244BV <- data.frame(X1372BV5244BV)
X1372BV5640BV <- data.frame(X1372BV5640BV)
X1372BV6164BV <- data.frame(X1372BV6164BV)

X5244BV5640BV <- data.frame(X5244BV5640BV)
X5244BV6164BV <- data.frame(X5244BV6164BV)

X5640BV6164BV <- data.frame(X5640BV6164BV)

X1372V5640V1372BV <- data.frame(X1372V5640V1372BV)
X1372V5640V5640BV <- data.frame(X1372V5640V5640BV)
X1372V5640V6164BV <- data.frame(X1372V5640V6164BV)

X1372V6164V1372BV <- data.frame(X1372V6164V1372BV)
X1372V6164V5640BV <- data.frame(X1372V6164V5640BV)
X1372V6164V6164BV <- data.frame(X1372V6164V6164BV)

X6164V5640V1372BV <- data.frame(X6164V5640V1372BV)
X6164V5640V5640BV <- data.frame(X6164V5640V5640BV)
X6164V5640V6164BV <- data.frame(X6164V5640V6164BV)

XAll3CardV <- data.frame(XAll3CardV)
XAll3Card1372BV <- data.frame(XAll3Card1372BV)
XAll3Card5640BV <- data.frame(XAll3Card5640BV)
XAll3Card6164BV <- data.frame(XAll3Card6164BV)

XAll3BankV <- data.frame(XAll3BankV)
XAll3Bank1372V <- data.frame(XAll3Bank1372V)
XAll3Bank5640V <- data.frame(XAll3Bank5640V)
XAll3Bank6164V <- data.frame(XAll3Bank6164V)

XAll13725640V <- data.frame(XAll13725640V)
XAll13726164V <- data.frame(XAll13726164V)
XAll56406164V <- data.frame(XAll56406164V)

XAll4CardV <- data.frame(XAll4CardV)
XAll4BankV <- data.frame(XAll4BankV)
XAll6V <- data.frame(XAll6V)
XAll8V <- data.frame(XAll8V)


s1 <- Macro["s1"]
s2 <- Macro["s2"]
s3 <- Macro["s3"]
y <- Macro["y"]

Macro2 <- data.frame(y, X1372C5244C, X1372C5640C, X1372C6164C, X1372C1372B, X1372C5244B, X1372C5640B, X1372C6164B, 
                     X5244C5640C, X5244C6164C, X5244C1372B, X5244C5244B, X5244C5640B, X5244C6164B, X5640C6164C, 
                     X5640C1372B, X5640C5244B, X5640C5640B, X5640C6164B, X6164C1372B, X6164C5244B, X6164C5640B, X6164C6164B, X1372B5244B, X1372B5640B, X1372B6164B, X5244B5640B, X5244B6164B, X5640B6164B, X1372C5640C1372B, X1372C5640C5640B, X1372C5640C6164B, X1372C6164C1372B, X1372C6164C5640B, X1372C6164C6164B, X6164C5640C1372B, X6164C5640C5640B, X6164C5640C6164B, 
                     XAll3Card, XAll3Card1372B, XAll3Card5640B, XAll3Card6164B, XAll3Bank, XAll3Bank1372C, XAll3Bank5640C, XAll3Bank6164C, XAll13725640, XAll13726164, XAll56406164, XAll4Card, XAll4Bank, XAll6, XAll8, s1, s2, s3)




Macro3 <- data.frame(y, X1372V5244V, X1372V5640V, X1372V6164V, X1372V1372BV, X1372V5244BV, X1372V5640BV, X1372V6164BV, 
                     X5244V5640V, X5244V6164V, X5244V1372BV, X5244V5244BV, X5244V5640BV, X5244V6164BV, X5640V6164V, 
                     X5640V1372BV, X5640V5244BV, X5640V5640BV, X5640V6164BV, X6164V1372BV, X6164V5244BV, X6164V5640BV, X6164V6164BV, X1372BV5244BV, X1372BV5640BV, X1372BV6164BV, X5244BV5640BV, X5244BV6164BV, X5640BV6164BV, X1372V5640V1372BV, X1372V5640V5640BV, X1372V5640V6164BV, X1372V6164V1372BV, X1372V6164V5640BV, X1372V6164V6164BV, X6164V5640V1372BV, X6164V5640V5640BV, X6164V5640V6164BV, 
                     XAll3CardV, XAll3Card1372BV, XAll3Card5640BV, XAll3Card6164BV, XAll3BankV, XAll3Bank1372V, XAll3Bank5640V, XAll3Bank6164V, XAll13725640V, XAll13726164V, XAll56406164V, XAll4CardV, XAll4BankV, XAll6V, XAll8V, s1, s2, s3)

Macro4 <- data.frame(c5640, c6164, b5640, b6164, v5640, v6164, bv5640, bv6164,
                     X5640C6164C, X5640C5640B, X5640C6164B, X6164C5640B, X6164C6164B, X5640B6164B, X6164C5640C5640B, X6164C5640C6164B, XAll56406164, 
                     X5640V6164V, X5640V5640BV, X5640V6164BV, X6164V5640BV, X6164V6164BV, X5640BV6164BV, X6164V5640V5640BV, X6164V5640V6164BV, XAll56406164V)


Macroall <- data.frame(y, c1372, c5640, c6164, b1372, b5640, b6164, v1372, v5640, v6164, bv1372, bv5640, bv6164,
                       X1372C5640C, X1372C6164C, X1372C1372B, X1372C5640B, X1372C6164B, 
                       X5640C6164C, 
                       X5640C1372B, X5640C5640B, X5640C6164B, X6164C1372B, X6164C5640B, X6164C6164B, X1372B5640B, X1372B6164B, X5640B6164B, X1372C5640C1372B, X1372C5640C5640B, X1372C5640C6164B, X1372C6164C1372B, X1372C6164C5640B, X1372C6164C6164B, X6164C5640C1372B, X6164C5640C5640B, X6164C5640C6164B, 
                       XAll3Card, XAll3Card1372B, XAll3Card5640B, XAll3Card6164B, XAll3Bank, XAll3Bank1372C, XAll3Bank5640C, XAll3Bank6164C, XAll13725640, XAll13726164, XAll56406164, XAll6,
                       X1372V5640V, X1372V6164V, X1372V1372BV, X1372V5640BV, X1372V6164BV, 
                       X5640V6164V, 
                       X5640V1372BV, X5640V5640BV, X5640V6164BV, X6164V1372BV, X6164V5640BV, X6164V6164BV, X1372BV5640BV, X1372BV6164BV, X5640BV6164BV, X1372V5640V1372BV, X1372V5640V5640BV, X1372V5640V6164BV, X1372V6164V1372BV, X1372V6164V5640BV, X1372V6164V6164BV, X6164V5640V1372BV, X6164V5640V5640BV, X6164V5640V6164BV, 
                       XAll3CardV, XAll3Card1372BV, XAll3Card5640BV, XAll3Card6164BV, XAll3BankV, XAll3Bank1372V, XAll3Bank5640V, XAll3Bank6164V, XAll13725640V, XAll13726164V, XAll56406164V, XAll6V, s1, s2, s3)
```

Comment: What are `c(vars_macro, vars_macro2, vars_macro3)`?

Comment: The loop loops through a list of variables contained in vars.

Comment: Yes, I mean that we don't see what your data look like

Comment: Not sure if it would change the answer, but I attached dput(Macro).  All vars do is call various variables or combination of variables in Macro.

Comment: You're growing objects within `for-loop` which is highly inefficient and not recommended in `R`. Please see these great posts to find out better ways to do it: [Efficient accumulation in R](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2015/07/efficient-accumulation-in-r/), 
[Applying a function over rows of a data frame](https://rpubs.com/wch/200398) & [Row-oriented workflows in R with the tidyverse](https://github.com/jennybc/row-oriented-workflows)

Comment: Thanks, would you mind posting a solution that accomplishes the objective?

Comment: You need to provide the ```c(vars_macro, vars_macro2, vars_macro3)```. Your code cannot be run as is.

Comment: @Cole see updated code, I reduced the variable to one (vars_macro).  The variables are not that material - I'm simply trying to speed up the code.

Comment: It's material to see what output you want. Now your code can be run.

Comment: I don't think your code as currently written takes advantage of the parallel cores. The reason your code did not speed up after registering the cores is because the for loop does not automagically take advantage of the parallel cores. You need to use the `foreach` function or functions from the `future` package as @Cole's answer does. That will make a much bigger difference than going from for loop to lapply.

Answer (score 1):

The `auto.arima` takes up the majority of time which means there's not much optimization. Each `auto.arima` takes about 200 milliseconds. `1:6` times 16 columns times 200 milliseconds is 19.2 seconds. On my machine, this solution takes up about 22 seconds to run without enabling any parallel cores. Not too shabby of overhead. **Final Edit:** With `future_lapply`, I got it from 22 seconds to 12 seconds on my 2-core i3. With 32-cores, you should be looking pretty good.

The biggest change is that I subset your `Macro` once for each time series loop (i.e., `rev(1:6)`). This helps not repeating the `y` subset for each varname.

Then, instead of an explicit loop, `lapply` is used which should be faster than a `for` loop.

One last note, I still couldn't get your code to run so I'm not sure if these are your intended results.

```
library(future.apply)
plan(multiprocess) 
all_outputs <- lapply(6:1,
                      function (z) {
                        x1 <- ts(Macro[-z, vars], start = c(2016, 3), frequency = 4)
                        y1 <- ts(Macro[-z, 'y'], start = c(2016, 3), frequency = 4)
                        t1 <- ts(Macro[nrow(Macro)-z+1, vars], start = c(2018, 4), frequency = 4)

                        fits <-
                          future_lapply(x1, function(x)
                            auto.arima(
                              y = y1,
                              xreg = x,
                              seasonal = TRUE
                            ))
                        outputs <-
                          lapply(vars,  function(x)
                            x = forecast(fits[[x]], xreg = t1[, x])$mean)

                        names(outputs) <- vars

                        outputs
                      }
                    )

#if you have data.table
data.table::rbindlist(all_outputs)
#or base works fine as well
do.call(rbind, all_outputs)
```

**edit2:** results

```
> do.call(rbind, all_outputs)
     c1372    c5244    c5640    c6164    b1372    b5244    b5640   
[1,] 207.3153 243.6196 240.3115 195.4832 244.7843 231.6605 236.5413
[2,] 206.3054 241.976  241.5821 198.7039 243.2236 239.3933 239.69  
[3,] 204.1035 244.3271 244.2875 218.5334 243.7765 239.1547 252.0341
[4,] 222.5313 242.494  234.2466 229.7297 242.8088 247.4714 242.9732
[5,] 228.2269 242.7452 222.5183 233.2577 242.0669 242.7832 242.8417
[6,] 237.058  241.8235 235.3313 242.1377 241.7233 241.8443 241.8192
     b6164    v1372    v5244    v5640    v6164    bv1372   bv5244  
[1,] 244.097  243.0404 242.4219 250.7803 245.2109 243.1929 230.8454
[2,] 245.59   239.6461 240.0976 249.8216 244.076  240.2225 239.4011
[3,] 248.9123 240.3455 241.308  256.1201 241.8166 239.2862 238.6731
[4,] 245.1561 240.3136 246.373  257.4908 243.991  241.2637 247.0656
[5,] 242.3743 241.8402 242.5925 252.1454 239.7479 242.9514 242.6109
[6,] 241.8072 241.3552 244.5711 237.4899 241.7374 241.8847 244.9614
     bv5640   bv6164  
[1,] 231.3937 241.8475
[2,] 231.5027 239.3111
[3,] 230.2004 239.2619
[4,] 230.8542 231.8769
[5,] 233.1609 236.7501
[6,] 232.2402 241.8176
```

**edit:** data

```
library(scales)
library(foreach) 
library(doParallel)
library(forecast)
library(future.apply)

plan(multiprocess) #for future_lapply

Macro <-
  structure(
    list(
      qtrs = structure(
        1:14,
        .Label = c(
          "15_Q3",
          "15_Q4",
          "16_Q1",
          "16_Q2",
          "16_Q3",
          "16_Q4",
          "17_Q1",
          "17_Q2",
          "17_Q3",
          "17_Q4",
          "18_Q1",
          "18_Q2",
          "18_Q3",
          "QQ_New"
        ),
        class = "factor"
      ),
      y = c(
        121.3,
        131.1,
        142.5,
        156.4,
        168.7,
        176.2,
        177,
        186.6,
        199.6,
        208.4,
        214,
        226.2,
        232.5,
        233.3
      ),
      c1372 = c(
        0.51798059487155,
        0.605074600778554,
        0.70840580233259,
        0.796638389230915,
        0.800936365512504,
        0.862507422705653,
        0.906587776772603,
        0.965869599669482,
        1.02057681299029,
        1.0173665712577,
        1.00815541019123,
        1.11026857023261,
        1.12549360199319,
        1.17070543044674
      ),
      c5244 = c(
        0.0158288398871533,
        0.0186529717846534,
        0.0335038479568057,
        0.0322124481706554,
        0.0473432307176583,
        0.0372644166954006,
        0.055124227441671,
        0.0462947124597511,
        0.0595395997947759,
        0.079813226336006,
        0.0632338684298483,
        0.0359582444979424,
        0.0399978873936274,
        0.0363530147033467
      ),
      c5640 = c(
        0.0695411232121069,
        0.0711030107194139,
        0.0768960904393596,
        0.0937721113616879,
        0.0912072768529112,
        0.0948627915873504,
        0.0898598251896699,
        0.102519015439631,
        0.117307571608132,
        0.116512410019832,
        0.112621649435311,
        0.113373707050245,
        0.11920732067264,
        0.11385677519257
      ),
      c6164 = c(
        0.165253620685311,
        0.180939722142955,
        0.204839371353829,
        0.230388360169478,
        0.245455819824873,
        0.250222069413121,
        0.267517323013963,
        0.301455130772129,
        0.312527568603722,
        0.318684362849784,
        0.336297671149745,
        0.385321973576628,
        0.393392171202544,
        0.414026295628249
      ),
      b1372 = c(
        0.220276379575007,
        0.232259423605283,
        0.239015099925248,
        0.29722406784095,
        0.305759227349267,
        0.314812674203001,
        0.373507924872403,
        0.376216626537958,
        0.450679682818151,
        0.422160030256414,
        0.398670890305128,
        0.380896038096525,
        0.339513818723946,
        0.365265284571949
      ),
      b5244 = c(
        0.0256963971001724,
        0.0308736893223339,
        0.0314727889765328,
        0.0342560993718647,
        0.0329261690808683,
        0.0341169107838618,
        0.0500316002161605,
        0.057066652393088,
        0.0637597978553195,
        0.102100656473269,
        0.109515398926193,
        0.0509080775409312,
        0.034576665601428,
        0.037353167421955
      ),
      b5640 = c(
        0.0610914743954476,
        0.0681070468175109,
        0.0680584203087885,
        0.0737178858316377,
        0.0657525044040775,
        0.0634389081514569,
        0.0655890933419926,
        0.0689747904574716,
        0.0653176858840394,
        0.0683221933318993,
        0.0692822163266979,
        0.0648739229545749,
        0.0613089747918081,
        0.0681802570906864
      ),
      b6164 = c(
        0.106769764392002,
        0.117293493937739,
        0.128632140410947,
        0.146139699267301,
        0.15999997720466,
        0.170137316488036,
        0.188733545209946,
        0.192072924866328,
        0.200314760101575,
        0.206572493122192,
        0.21531555211795,
        0.187877279779437,
        0.161952291803993,
        0.160944253061549
      ),
      v1372 = c(
        0.00268999015293817,
        0.00312395322452212,
        0.00339511453015627,
        0.00345686458302532,
        0.00342490795325169,
        0.0036875222492476,
        0.00361618758896395,
        0.00355297766248592,
        0.00386182842589497,
        0.00356454140879668,
        0.00347191673410727,
        0.00363595803623375,
        0.00374222181870868,
        0.00371078757415556
      ),
      v5244 = c(
        0.000480051602474059,
        0.00042588395300854,
        0.0005605459198973,
        0.000529571165782351,
        0.00057240403833901,
        0.000468179333138233,
        0.000653241119295764,
        0.000455570432040571,
        0.000535395675184177,
        0.00138501873189088,
        0.00114060122318986,
        0.000320532455933637,
        0.000333175133801828,
        0.000314970929257286
      ),
      v5640 = c(
        0.000839152227642805,
        0.000878653169087127,
        0.00086250329626335,
        0.000928749230480325,
        0.000952705037621405,
        0.0009145284719627,
        0.000862662166602764,
        0.000861675351344781,
        0.000900555099811469,
        0.000846321708899047,
        0.000869990227889332,
        0.000889602926022706,
        0.000847332392691765,
        0.000745645512078392
      ),
      v6164 = c(
        0.00174116886286925,
        0.00190736857470478,
        0.00204206516831707,
        0.00208434471661794,
        0.0022434016778137,
        0.00215767033473045,
        0.00216675412062837,
        0.00211218329813293,
        0.00222445645154173,
        0.00210022505915819,
        0.00196775099859493,
        0.00205851514065652,
        0.00187858647947073,
        0.00198038712502613
      ),
      bv1372 = c(
        0.00142360941776777,
        0.00151188642851632,
        0.00157840305106086,
        0.00168297006976765,
        0.00157809381382463,
        0.00180299614944991,
        0.00285754565464732,
        0.0026777621396315,
        0.00314015380649578,
        0.00293231409618566,
        0.00290686161843522,
        0.00248890293023165,
        0.00168251123284542,
        0.00179265933772828
      ),
      bv5244 = c(
        0.000582722401914161,
        0.000711777965499918,
        0.000761910243648493,
        0.000805854835145839,
        0.000736857013245957,
        0.000833892120648163,
        0.0013602408759186,
        0.0015050207801102,
        0.0016936381650882,
        0.00295309680744017,
        0.0031773319850428,
        0.00106962198904438,
        0.000593441969063344,
        0.000574791244792
      ),
      bv5640 = c(
        0.00115351432401665,
        0.00132428243672085,
        0.00136224787475921,
        0.00141606633583978,
        0.00116049625522213,
        0.000858609082150378,
        0.000908098663997447,
        0.000935982449156028,
        0.000899912473850066,
        0.000835053614508394,
        0.000872837946479594,
        0.000833516238462063,
        0.000726891442062557,
        0.000774037355521608
      ),
      bv6164 = c(
        0.000926271545004555,
        0.00105864530300842,
        0.00109611375444535,
        0.00117219207771791,
        0.00122508269987305,
        0.00135585463133827,
        0.00195926581029822,
        0.00187620455518874,
        0.00206572868014085,
        0.00213169451258196,
        0.00205259028597028,
        0.00136013066654879,
        0.000919533667669498,
        0.0010609844820593
      ),
      s1 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
             1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L),
      s2 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
             0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L),
      s3 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
             1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
      date = structure(
        c(1L, 1L,
          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
        .Label = "2018-09-30",
        class = "factor"
      )
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-14L)
  )

# Loads variables
vars_macro <- c("c1372", "c5244", "c5640", "c6164", "b1372", "b5244", "b5640", 
                  "b6164", "v1372", "v5244", "v5640", "v6164", "bv1372", "bv5244", 
                  "bv5640", "bv6164")
vars = c(vars_macro)

all_outputs <- lapply(6:1,
                      function (z) {
                        x1 <- ts(Macro[-z, vars], start = c(2016, 3), frequency = 4)
                        y1 <- ts(Macro[-z, 'y'], start = c(2016, 3), frequency = 4)
                        t1 <- ts(Macro[nrow(Macro)-z+1, vars], start = c(2018, 4), frequency = 4)

                        fits <-
                          future_lapply(x1, function(x)
                            auto.arima(
                              y = y1,
                              xreg = x,
                              seasonal = TRUE
                            ))
                        outputs <-
                          lapply(vars,  function(x)
                            x = forecast(fits[[x]], xreg = t1[, x])$mean)

                        names(outputs) <- vars

                        outputs
                      }
                    )

data.table::rbindlist(all_outputs)
do.call(rbind, all_outputs)
```

Comment: I can't get your code to work either.  Did you define function(x)?  The issue with the code is not all vars variable belong to the Macro table.  Some of the vars variables were generated as combinations of the variables in the Macro table (thus they cannot be found in Macro).

Comment: I edited my code with the all the data and packages in the second window. I ran it and it worked in RStudio. The ```lapply()``` includes an anonymous function. The variables you updated for vars_macro were all included in the Macro data.frame.

Comment: Hi @Cole, see above - I originally didn't want to include all code and variables, because I thought it was quite a lot, but see above.  I think I've included everything.

Comment: I replaced the vars variable with vars_macro, since you are only calling variables explicitly in Macro.  When I ran this code, it returned no errors, but I tried calling the output through outputs and got nothing.  Any idea?

Comment: You have to do ```all_outputs``` or do the line ```do.call(rbind, all_outputs)```. See edit with data output.  I'm not going to incorporate the rest of your data - it's already at 22 seconds for me with 16 columns let alone 120 variables. You should do a subset of the 16 variables I used and see if there are any time savings on your machine. I expect there would be some but again, your weak link is the ```auto.arima``` function. There's not much to do about that.

Comment: See last edit on third paragraph. A benefit of lapply is that now you can use future_lapply from future.apply package to do that operation in parallel.

Comment: Yeah, use future_lapply. My 2-core practically did it twice as fast going from 22 seconds down to 12 seconds. I'll edit the answer one last time.