# Speeding up function applied via future_mapply

Tags: r, mapply

I have written a function to undertake backward stepwise arima modelling for 91 time series models.

The function has two inputs:

```
  1. a list of time series objects
  2. a list of data frames
```

The function is as follows:

```
backward_stepwise<-function(x, y){
  repeat{
    arima_result<-auto_arima(x)
    last_col<-colnames(x)[ncol(x)]
    names(arima_result$coef)<-gsub(pattern = "xreg", replacement = last_col,
                                  x = names(arima_result$coef))
    arima_pvals<-p_calc(arima_result)
    arima_outputs<-run_outputs(arima_result, arima_pvals)
    arima_ranked<-rank_pval(arima_outputs)
    remove_num_one<-remove_one(arima_ranked)
    y<-subset(y, select = colnames(y) != remove_num_one)
    x<-as.ts(y)

    if(min(arima_ranked$rank, na.rm = TRUE) != 1){
      break
    }

  }

  return(list(arima_result, arima_ranked))
}
```

where:

```
auto_arima<-function(x){
  arima_results<-auto.arima(x[,2], xreg = x[,3:ncol(x)], approximation = FALSE, stepwise = FALSE)
}
```

```
p_calc<-function(x){
  p_vals<-round((1-pnorm(abs(x$coef)/sqrt(diag(x$var.coef))))*2, digits = 3)
  p_vals<-broom::tidy(p_vals)
}
```

```
run_outputs<-function(x, y){
  outputs<-x$coef
  outputs<-broom::tidy(outputs)
  outputs<-cbind(outputs, y)
  outputs<-outputs[,c(1,2,4)] # selecting columns to include
  setNames(object = outputs, nm = c("term", "coef", "pval")) # naming colums of outputs

}
```

```
rank_pval<-function(x){
  x["rank"]<-NA
  cond<-{substr(x$term,1,2) != "ar" &
      substr(x$term,1,2) != "ma" &
      substr(x$term, 1, nchar(x$term)) != "intercept" &
      substr(x$term, 1, nchar(x$term)) != "drift" &
      x$pval > 0.2}

  x[cond, "rank"]<-rank(-x[cond,]$pval, na.last = NA)

  return(x)

}
```

```
remove_one<-function(x){
  x<-subset(x$term, subset = x$rank == 1)

}
```

```
cond_select<-function(x, y){
  x<-subset(x, select = names(x) != y)
  x<-ts(x)
}
```

The quickest implementation of this (68.69 seconds) is by using:

```
plan(multiprocess)
ts_outputs<-future_mapply(backward_stepwise, list_ts_actual, list_df_actual, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

What are my options to speed this up further? Ultimately I want to this run as quick as possible on a local machine.

I am using a Dell XPS 15 9560 with Intel(R) Core(TM) i&7-7770HQ CPU - 4 cores, 8 logical processors.

I'm aware that you can't parallel process through mcmapply as you can't fork on Windows OS.

I tried compiling the actual functions with cmpfun but didnt get any speed increases.

Possibilities:

- data.tables and matrices are quicker than data frames
- removing the rank function and simply allocating to the highest p_value

What are my other options?

Appreciate any assistance or direction

Comment: Have you profiled any steps? My limited experience with auto.arima is that the function itself takes a long time. With the ```repeat``` loop, you might be hitting the function over and over. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55778926/optimizing-for-loop-for-speed/56091145#56091145

Comment: @Cole, I have profiled and the majority of time was on something called socketSelect. Thanks for the link, it gave me an idea to subset the time series as opposed to the data frame and then converting to time series, so I can use lapply as opposed to mapply